# Powershell - Search json tree

Tags: json, powershell, psobject, select-object

I have a json structure in a file my.json that looks similar to below:

```
{
   "key1":{
      "key1A":{
         "someKey":"someValue"
      },
      "key1B":{
         "someKey":"someValue"
      }
   },
   "key2":{
      "key2A":{
         "someKey":"someValue"
      },
      "key2B":{
         "someKey":"someValue"
      }         
   },       
   "key3":{
      "key3A":{
         "someKey":"someValue"
      },
      "key3B":{
         "someKey":"someValue"
      }
   }
}
```

Using powershell I would like to search for "node" key1B and select it. The assumptions are

1. key1B only occurs once in the whole tree
2. The search term (key1B) can either be a root element or a child of a root element.

If I were to know the parent under which node key1B is I could use below:

```
Get-Content -Raw my.json | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -ExpandProperty key1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty key1B
```

How can I make above select generic so that the node I'm searching for can be either in the root or a child of the root?

Comment: Your JSON isn't syntactically correct, `"key1"` and `"key2"` both have no closing `}`

Comment: @NekoMusume Sorry about that, fixed it.

Comment: Try `((Get-Content -Raw my.json | ConvertFrom-Json) | gm | ? {$_.Definition -imatch "key1A"}).name` This will get the parent node of `key1A`

Comment: Was able to grab content of `key1a` with your JSON as `$testJson` like so: ```$($testJson | ConvertFrom-Json).$((($testJson | ConvertFrom-Json) | gm | ? {$_.Definition -imatch "key1A"}).name).key1a``` Very convuluted but would be easier if I had a separate variable with the actual converted json, proof of concept though

Answer (score 2):

[jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) has a [recursive descent](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#RecursiveDescent:..) `..` operator that can search all the keys like xpath `//`.

```
get-content file.json | jq '.. | .key1B? | select(. != null)'

{
  "someKey1b": "someValue1b"
}
```

Comment: Is `jq` an alias? My system cannot find `jq`

Comment: @NekoMusume No it's an external command to download.

Answer (score 2):

```
# convert as a Hashtable
$json = Get-Content -Raw .\my.json | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable

# a root element
$json.key1B

# a child of a root element
$json.Values.key1B

# descendant
function findByKey {
  param($json, $key)
  if ($json.$key) { $json.$key }
  else {
    $json.Values | ? values | % { findByKey $_ $key } | select -First 1
  }
}

findByKey $json "key1B"
```

Comment: The only thing is it requires powershell 7.

Answer (score 1):

You can find `Key1A` or whatever key you are looking for by looking at the definition column of `Get-Member`.

Let's define your JSON As variable `$TestJson`:

```
$testJson = @"
{
   "key1":{
      "key1A":{
         "someKey":"someValue"
      },
      "key1B":{
         "someKey":"someValue"
      }
   },
   "key2":{
      "key2A":{
         "someKey":"someValue"
      },
      "key2B":{
         "someKey":"someValue"
      }
   },         
   "key3":{
      "key3A":{
         "someKey":"someValue"
      },
      "key3B":{
         "someKey":"someValue"
      }
   }
} 
"@
$testJson = $testJson | ConvertFrom-Json
```

We are looking for `Key1A` in `$testJson` which we do not know is under the parent node `key1`, we can do this by looking at the output of `$testJson | gm`

```
$testJson | gm


   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
key1        NoteProperty System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject key1=@{key1A=; key1B=}
key2        NoteProperty System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject key2=@{key2A=; key2B=}
key3        NoteProperty System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject key3=@{key3A=; key3B=}
```

We can see here that all of the nodes and their sub-nodes are listed in the definitions tab, with bigger JSONs, we wouldn't be able to see the whole definitions tab with this so we could wither to one of these two things:

```
$testJson | gm | select-object "Definition"
($testJson | gm).Definition
```

So if we want to find `Key1A` we can do

```
$testJson | gm | ? {$_.Definition -imatch "key1A"}
```

Which finds the definition in where `key1a` is in (case-insensitive as specified by `-i` instead of `-c`) which gives us the output of

```
   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name MemberType   Definition
---- ----------   ----------
key1 NoteProperty System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject key1=@{key1A=; key1B=}
```

Where as you can see the parent node is `key1` and we can grab that as well with

```
($testJson | gm | ? {$_.Definition -imatch "key1A"}).name
key1
```

And to view the content of `key1` we can do

```
$($testJson).$(($testJson | gm | ? {$_.Definition -imatch "key1A"}).name)

key1A                key1B
-----                -----
@{someKey=someValue} @{someKey=someValue}
```

And `key1a`

```
$($testJson).$(($testJson | gm | ? {$_.Definition -imatch "key1A"}).name).key1a

someKey
-------
someValue
```